# Python Selenium Web Scraping - Hidden Text / Javascript?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract some text from a page using Python and Selenium The text is visible to me, but I can't work out how to extract it - I think the text was created in Java.

Im on the URL: "https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/hz/fba/profitabilitycalculator/index?lang=en_GB" and have entered the product id 'B00FRJ1R4M' for example, pressed search, then entered '20' in the Amazon Fulfilment Item Price box and pressed calculate.

I'm trying to extract the '-5.59' but to no avail.

[image]

The closest I think I've got is the follwing code:

```
cost = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='afn-fees']/dl/dd[15]/input")

print(cost.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
print(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML", cost))
```

But this for returns 'None'.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.get_attribute("value")`, since this is an `input`, and simplify your locator:

```
cost = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.cost-total")
print(cost.get_attribute("value"))
```

Here `input.cost-total` CSS selector would match an `input` element having `cost-total` class, which is quite readable and reliable locator in this case.